# Dynamic File Upload Control removes the selected file when adding additional C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, multifile-uploader

I have a form in where user is able to add as many as attachment they want through update control by pressing "Add Attachment" button. They should select an attachment type every time they upload a new file. But if I select a file and choose the type and then press the "Add Attachment" button, it removes my first selection from File upload and File Type drop down. I used even UpdatePanel but still the same.
Here is the picture:

[Upload Control Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yAy1O.jpg)

Here is my C# code:

```
    protected void btnAddAttachment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (ViewState["AdditionalFilesTable"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = (DataTable)ViewState["AdditionalFilesTable"];

            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;
            drCurrentRow = dt.NewRow();

            drCurrentRow[0] = "";

            dt.Rows.Add(drCurrentRow); // add grid values in to row and add row to the blank table
            ViewState["AdditionalFilesTable"] = dt;

            GridView1.DataSource = dt; // bind new datatable to grid
            GridView1.DataBind();

        }
        else
        {
            CreateFileUploadtable();
        }
    }
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
   <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
   <ContentTemplate>
        <tr>
             <td colspan="3" style="text-align:center; padding-top:25px; font-size:medium;text-align:center">                      
                     <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" style="margin:0px auto;">
                         <Columns>
                             <asp:TemplateField>
                                 <HeaderTemplate>
                                   Upload Files
                                 </HeaderTemplate>

                                 <ItemTemplate>
                                     <table style="width:100%" >
                                         <tr>
                                             <td>
                                                 File:
                                             </td>
                                             <td>
                                                 <asp:FileUpload ID="fUpControl" runat="server" Width="300px" />
                                                 <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("FileContent") %>' />
                                                 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Upload File!" ControlToValidate="fUpControl" Display="Dynamic" ValidationGroup="WireTransfer" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Smaller" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                         </td>
                                         <td>
                                                 File type:
                                         </td>
                                         <td>
                                                 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlFileType" runat="server" Width="200px">
                                                     <asp:ListItem Value="0">-- Select Type --</asp:ListItem>
                                                     <asp:ListItem Value="Invoice">Invoice</asp:ListItem>
                                                     <asp:ListItem Value="Email">Email</asp:ListItem>
                                                     <asp:ListItem Value="WireDetails">Wire Details</asp:ListItem>
                                                     <asp:ListItem Value="WireConfirmation">Wire Confirmation</asp:ListItem>
                                                     <asp:ListItem Value="BankStatement">Bank Statement</asp:ListItem>
                                                     <asp:ListItem Value="ClosingDocument">Closing Document</asp:ListItem>
                                                 </asp:DropDownList>
                                                 <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField2" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("FileType") %>' />
                                                 <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Please Select File Type!" ControlToValidate="ddlFileType" Display="Dynamic" InitialValue="0" ValidationGroup="WireTransfer" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Smaller" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                             </td>
                                             <td>
                                                 <asp:Button ID="btnDeleteAttachment" runat="server" Text="Delete" Width="80px" OnClick="btnDeleteAttachment_Click"/>
                                             </td>
                                         </tr>
                                     </table>
                                 </ItemTemplate>
                             </asp:TemplateField>
                         </Columns>
                     </asp:GridView>
                 </td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td style="text-align:center; font-size:medium; font-style:oblique; padding-bottom:5px;" colspan="3">
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnAddAttachment" runat="server" Text="Add Attachment" width="150px" OnClick="btnAddAttachment_Click"  />

             <tr>
                 <td style="text-align:center; font-size:medium; font-style:oblique; padding-bottom:5px;" colspan="3">
                     &nbsp;</td>
             </tr>
             <tr>
                 <td style="text-align:center; font-size:medium; font-style:oblique; padding-bottom:5px;" colspan="3">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" width="150px" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" ValidationGroup="WireTransfer"/>                        
                 </td>
             </tr>
         </ContentTemplate>
         <Triggers>
                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" />
         </Triggers>
         </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: when you click add attachment, it make post back and all of selected files should go away. if you want to keep those, you have to use java script to create extra attachment control instead.

Comment: @TonyDong I had it before with java script but then I wasn't able to add they type drop down for it with java script. I mean I didn't know how I could  add the types.

Comment: you can use var fu1 = document.getElementById("<%= FileUpload1.ClientID %>").value; to get upload file name and save it into hidden field. var x = document.getElementById('<%= hdnSomeField.ClientID %>');
            x.value = 'hi';
 after post back, you can get it value from hidden field and set it back to upload file control.